# when i print a table using javaScript the half content of table is hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

[This is the print preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjCxN.png).

This is my JavaScript code for printing the table:

```
function PrintElem(divID) {
    var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
    var printcontent = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
}
```

This is my CSS for printing the table:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    @page
    {
        size:  auto;
        margin: 0;
    }
    a[href]:after {
        content: none !important;
    }
    html
    {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        margin: 0;
    }
    body
    {
        margin: 5mm 15mm 20mm 15mm;
    }
</style>
```

When I print my table half the `td`'s are not printing.

This is the table which I want to print:

```
    <div class="table-responsive" id="myDiv">
        <span id="hide" hidden>2</span>
        <table class="table" border="">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><b>S.No.</b></td>
                <td><b>Order Number</b></td>
                <td><b>Doctor Name</b></td>
                <td><b>Medicine Availability</b></td>
                <td><b>Action</b></td>

            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">06.03-VNS742</a></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <input type="text" name="id[]" value="298" hidden=""/>
                        <input type="submit" id="submit-form" class="hidden"/>
                        <a href="#"><input type="submit" value="Update" hidden=""/></a>
                        <input type="text" name="id[]" value="300" hidden=""/>
                        <input type="submit" id="submit-form" class="hidden"/>
                        <a href="#"><input type="submit" value="Update" hidden=""></a>
                        <table class="table" border="">
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>S.No.</b></td>
                                <td><b>Medicine Name</b></td>
                                <td><b>Quantity</b></td>
                                <td><b>Unit</b></td>
                                <td><b>Availability</b></td>
                                <td><b>Remark</b></td>
                                <form action="processAvailability.php" method="POST"></form>
                            </tr>
                            <tr align="center">
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="medicine_name[]" value="Apml"/></td>
                                <!-- <td>Apml</td> -->
                                <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="15"/></td>
                                <td>
                                    <select name="med_unit_type[]" onchange="CheckColors(this.value);">
                                        <option>Tablet</option>
                                        <option>Strips</option>
                                        <option>Bottle</option>
                                        <option>Tablet</option>
                                        <option>Other</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="order_number" value="06.03-VNS742" hidden=""/>
                                    <select name="availability[]">
                                        <option value="Not Available">Not Available</option>
                                        <option value="Available">Available</option>
                                        <option value="Not Available">Not Available</option>
                                        <option value="Partially Available">Partially Available</option>
                                        <option value="Confusion">Confusion</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>

                                <td><input type="text" class="css-input" name="remark[]" value=""
                                           placeholder="Write Remark Here"/></td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="submit-form">Save</label>
                </td>
                <td><a href="#">Reschedule Order</a></td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: And why are you appending `html`, `head`, `title` and `body` tags to `body`?

Comment: Now you can help me @phreakv6

Comment: I add the table code @Apb

Comment: You don't need to delete HTML to print... just use a [print style sheet](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/).

Comment: Can you point me to the original page where you are facing the problem? Am not sure what you mean by "half the table is hidden"

Comment: I am doing this on localhost. half table mean last two column are hidden in print view. and in bottom scroll is shown. @phreakv6

Answer (score 0):

I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/46huszds/) so we can explore the problem.

When I resize the HTML section, I see all the columns without problems. Can you provide a screenshot of what is happening?

You can probably try this.

```
.table-responsive {
    width:"100%";
}
```

Comment: yeah i will send u screenshot. give me your mail id.

Comment: Please update the question with the screenshot so others too can help.

Comment: i add the screenshot @phreakv6

Comment: Thanks. It is still hard to make out. Is the table part of a div? Are you able to scroll horizontally to see the rest of the table?

Comment: yes table is the part of div, in webpage no scroll is required. But print view is in screenshot. @phreakv6

Comment: If it is for printing, perhaps the table width is too wide to fit horizontally in the format your are trying to print? You will have to fix the size of the table and reduce font sizes if you will still want to print it that way.

Comment: yeah i want to print that table. okay i will try.